# Is it possible to compare two excel sheets using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a requirement where I need to compare two excel sheets and highlight the differences. Reason why I insist for JavaScript is that ,in cypress i have automated front end part until excel sheets download using JavaScript. After download, need to compare two of them for which cypress does not support the comparison part and that needs to be coded without cypress as it is not on web. At this point I am looking for a solution.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json
to convert those excel files to json and then write the necessary logic for comparing both resulting jsons